# Rails nested form with has_many :through, not saving the data to joining table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am kinda new to Rails and this is my first post to StackOverflow.

Say I have 3 models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :order => :title
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :promo_products
  has_many :promotions, :through => :promo_products, :foreign_key => :promotion_id
  before_destroy :ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item
  before_destroy :ensure_not_referenced_by_any_promo_product

  validates :title, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  validates :description, :presence => true
  validates :price, :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0.01}
  private
  def ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item
    if line_items.empty?
      return true
    else
      errors.add(:base, 'Line Items present')
      return false
    end
  end
  def ensure_not_referenced_by_any_promo_product
    if promo_products.empty?
      return true
    else
      errors.add(:base, 'Some promotions are still in effect')
      return false
    end
  end
end

class Promotion < ActiveRecord::Base

  CART_OR_PRODUCT = ['Cart', 'Product']
  PROMOTION_TYPE = ['Percentage based', 'Value based']

  has_many :promo_products
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :promo_products
  has_many :products, :through => :promo_products, :foreign_key => :product_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
  #attr_accessible :promo_products_attributes, :title, :description, :cart_or_product, :promotion_type, :discount, :minimum_price, :minimum_quantity

  validates :title, :description, :presence => true
  validates :cart_or_product, :inclusion => {:in => CART_OR_PRODUCT, :message =>
  "is invlaid. Please select a valid option"}
  validates :promotion_type, :inclusion => {:in => PROMOTION_TYPE, :message =>
  "is invalid. Please select a valid option"}
  validates :discount, :minimum_price, :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0.00}
  validates :minimum_quantity, :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0}

end

class PromoProduct < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :promotion
  belongs_to :product
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
end
```

In the promotions new page, I would like to show list of products that could be part of a promotion. A user may select 0, 1 or more products, depending on the type of promotion.

In the action new of promotions_controller, I built like this:

```
@promotion.promo_products.build.build_product
```

In the _form of promotions, I needed to show the list of products for user to select. I made a nested form like:

```
<%= form_for(@promotion) do |f| %>
  <!-- other promotion fields -->
  <%= f.fields_for :promo_products do |pp| %>
    <%= pp.fields_for :products do |p| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label "Products" %><br />
        <%= collection_select :promo_product, :product_id, Product.all, :id, :title {:selected => @promotion.product_ids}, {:multiple => true} %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I have 2 issues.

1. First my code throws an error:
   ArgumentError in PromotionsController#new
   No association found for name `products'. Has it been defined yet?
   If I change the line in PromoProduct model:
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
   to
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :product
   Then there are no errors, and everything works fine.
2. The data doesn't get saved to promo_product table. I have the create action in promo_product controller as:

   ```
   def create
     @promotion = current_promotion
     products = Product.select(:id => params[:product_id])
     products.each do |p|
       promo_product = @promotion.promo_products.build(p)
       promo_product.save
     end
     #@promo_product = PromoProduct.new(params[:promo_product])
     redirect_to promotions_path
   end
   ```

   How can I go about it?

Thank you.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem(s). Followed the idea given here [link](https://gist.github.com/2820294). Seems to be working fine. Removde the creation from promo_product create action and made it work through Promotion create action.

Answer (score 1):

1. You shouldn't put the "accept_nested_attribute_for" in the association table PromoProducts. It should exist in the model that you want to use for creating association to another model. "accept_nested_attribute_for" IIRC simply inserts an "[association]_attributes=" method for your model. For instance, if you add this method to your Product class for Promotion, you will get "promotion_attributes=" method inserted in the Product class. Then a nested form can use this function to create new objects with a hash that represents the model and association.
2. Base on the above, the create action shouldn't be in PromoProduct controller, instead it should be in Promotion controller.

   ```
   <%= form_for(@promotion) do |f| %>
     <!-- other promotion fields -->
     <%= f.fields_for :products do |pp| %>
       <div class="field">
         <%= f.label "Products" %><br />
         <%= collection_select :promo_product, :product_id, Product.all, :id, :title {:selected => @promotion.product_ids}, {:multiple => true} %>
       </div>
     <% end %>
   <% end %>
   ```

I don't know without trying if the above collection_select line is correct. But you can debug this by checking the parameter returned by the form to the controller in the server console log. Basically you should see a nested hash of

```
{:promotion => {:products => ...}}
```

Let me know if you need more help on this. In my solution I used a combination of select_tag and options_from_collection_for_select. (But I don't recall the behavior of all these offhand without looking at the API doc.)

Lastly, do you need the :through model? I *think* since you created the through model you need to handle saving that in your create action. But since you don't have other attributes on the PromoProducts table I wonder if you want to simply leave it as a HABTM association and let rails deal with the rest?